# Jquery Flot - Set hoverable for individual data-series

Tags: jquery, flot

I have just yesterday begun using a JQuery graphing plugin called Flot. I am trying to plot multiple series while only allowing certain series to be hoverable. The [API](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) stipulates that data level options allow setting hoverable true/false. This seems however to be ignored and only graph level options are taking.

Here are my data level options:

```
var datasets = [
    { color: "green", data: data1, label: "Speed", lines: { show: true} },
    { color: "red", data: data2, label: "N01"} 
];
```

Here are my graph level options:

```
var options = { series: { bubbles: { active: true, show: true, fill: true, lineWidth: 2} }, grid: { show: true, hoverable: true, clickable: true} };
```

However as can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/ztqaX/) the above settings cause both data-series to be hoverable. From my understanding of the API I should be able to amend the above setting to the following:

```
var datasets = [
    { color: "green", data: data1, label: "Speed", lines: { show: true}, hoverable: false, clickable: false},
    { color: "red", data: data2, label: "N01", hoverable: true, clickable: true} 
];
```

This however doesn't work. Please can someone show me how to set which series are hoverable and clickable and which aren't.

Thanks from Cape Town, South Africa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the bubbles plugin.  If you remove `series: {bubbles: ...}}`, you'll see that the per-series hoverable/clickable options do work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out DNS. I wish to try my hand at a few things using flot. Would you mind if I mailed you a question or two?

Comment: Ask on the forums (http://groups.google.com/group/flot-graphs); I'll see them, and that way other users will as well.

Comment: That sounds great. I shall post some questions tomorrow as Devin de Vries. Thanks!

Comment: Ok my first series of questions are up :) Thanks for pointing me to the group!